# Very strange javascript sorting values behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been messing around with this for hours and the only thing I can narrow it down to is that if there is 14 elements to sort, it doesn't work properly, but if there is thirteen, it works fine.

I am trying to do a basic sort of `DIV` elements by the price values they hold inside.

Here is the simple html -

```
<div class="wrap">
    <button id="numBnt">Numerical</button>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£10.35</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£21.35</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£21.35</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£102.35</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£10.35</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£10.35</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£10.95</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£100.35</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£100.05</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£200.00</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <h2>£5510.25</h2>

        </div>
         <div class="box">
             <h2>£19.80</h2>

        </div>
  <div class="box">
             <h2>£5510.25</h2>

        </div>
          <div class="box">
             <h2>£510.25</h2>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript

```
var $divs = $("div.box");


$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text().replace(/£/g, '')) > parseFloat($(b).find("h2").text().replace(/£/g, ''));
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

With 13 div elements, the divs are sorted perfectly.

here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/380/

Then if I add another and make it 14 divs, the sort doesn't work correctly.

here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/378/

I am litrally banging my head of the table! Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: problem is your code only returns a boolean. a sort callback has to return THREE values. `+1,0,-1` to indicate greater-than,equal,less-than.

Comment: Just in the interest of completeness for anyone reads this, there's no requirement to return the specific values `+1` or `-1`. All the sort function cares about is the *sign* of the result, not the magnitude, so those can be any positive number and any negative number. In any case you're 100% right on the general concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a - b` instead of `a > b`

```
$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text().replace(/£/g, '')) - parseFloat($(b).find("h2").text().replace(/£/g, ''));
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/381/

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your fiddles are working, and it has nothing to do with the number of elements.

This works though:

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        var a = parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text().replace(/£/g, ''));
        var b = parseFloat($(b).find("h2").text().replace(/£/g, ''));

        return a - b;
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

The sort function on comparing two items should return `0` if they are equal, *a positive number* if first is greater than second, *a negative number* otherwise.

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/382/).

Comment: Since `a` and `b` are numbers, you can simply `return a - b;` instead of all the comparisons. If this were a case where you *did* need to use comparisons instead of subtraction (e.g. if `a` and `b` were strings), I definitely don't recommend using two different forms of comparison (the `if` statement for equality and the conditional operator for inequality). That is very confusing. Instead I would use `return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;`. That keeps a consistent pattern going which helps readability.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, I was under the impression that sort expects one of -1, 0 and 1. Just checked the doc and saw it just requires less than 0, 0 or greater than 0. That said I'll update my answer. But I don't think it was confusing as you suggested (based on my original impression), rather it oversimplified it. Thanks for pointing it out to me though, it got me to update myself. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the update, Igwe, looks good! I overstated things when I said the previous code was "very confusing", sorry. All I meant was that it was a bit inconsistent. Of course anyone reading the code would be able to figure out what it did - the code was perfectly clear and readable. But they might scratch their head wondering why the first comparison used an `if` statement and the next one used a conditional operator. If you are doing two comparisons in a row, it helps people reading the code if you use a consistent technique for both - that's all I meant. Keep up the good work!